# Can't connect to TFS by IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a strange issue. I try to connect to TFS by Visual Studio 2013 and by IE. I have TFS31003 error by VS and HTTP 401 error by IE. But I'm able to connect to same TFS by Chrome and FireFox. And I 'm able to do this from another computer by VS and IE. So, I'm sure that my credentials are valid and my account has necessary permissions. I tried to clear cookies, IE cache, Visual Studio cache. I've updated the IE from IE 8 to IE 11. I've even reinstalled the Windows (I use Windows 7). But it have not helped me.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What TFS server are you using? On-premise TFS server or Visual Studio Online server?

Answer (score 2):

Clear the Cache Credentials for the TFS Server that Windows has on your machine.

You can see them in the Control Panel under: "Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager" (or just type "Credentials" into the Start Menu).

Just browse down to the entry that matches, expand it and then click "Remove".

Comment: I've reinstalled the Windows. So, there are no any TFS credentials in Credential Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to clear the cache in  C:\Users\username(Team Explorer user name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

if that does not help also on the server side under:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache_v11.0

(The versions might be different)